# redirect to root for sepcific url path on HAproxy

Tags: redirect, haproxy

I have Haproxy configuration for proxying website, but i have some problem to redirect url to root if have some specifics url path

I need redirecting user to root if access /abc path
Example Code

```
frontend        http-in
    bind            *:9001
    option          httplog
    acl mobile_ua   hdr_sub(user-agent) -i -f /etc/haproxy/user-agent-mobile.lst
    acl web_load    path_beg /abc /def
    use_backend     b_mob if mobile_ua
    default_backend b_web
backend         b_mob
    option httplog
    mode http
    server s1 mobile.domain.com:8080
backend         b_web
    mode http
    server s1 web.domain.com:8080
```

I want if url path begin with /abc or /def (acl **web_load**) how to make it redirecting to root of url path (remove path url)

Thank you

Comment: People sometimes say "redirect" when they actually mean *rewrite the path*.  A redirect sends the browser to a different URL.  A rewrite just changes the path on is way to the backend.  I don't see either of those things in the config.  Which are you trying to do?

Comment: Hello @Michael-sqlbot i mean to redirecting browser (sends the browser to root path) if browser open path  in('abc', 'def')

Comment: `http-request redirect location / if web_load`